# Buttons with digits values input and buffering in calculator

Tags: java, string, wicket, calculator

I am trying to create a simple calculator using Wicket framework in Eclipse. So I changed my markup to add buttons with digits. I am trying to make this buttons work in the same way as just inputting from the keyboard, but I have some problems. I am using two hidden fields - input, buf for writing inputted value and for showing final value correspondingly.

So I was thinking that I can write current buf value to some String (current) and then add to it inputted value. This current string would be assigned back to buf and displayed. But instead for digits, 7,8 input field cleans up, and I can`t create numbers longer than 1 digit.

While other digits display something like *null453* in buf. So in this case, long numbers can be created, but short ones can not because inputted values are just glued into one number in buf. And this number does nit react to any operations - subtraction, multiplication. Instead, they are added to buf string.

How do I modify my onSubmit() method for each button, so that numbers can be composed of several digits without null in buf and that they would react to mathematical operations?
I will be very grateful for any help.

My code is a bit messy, sorry for that. I am just learning this technology.

```
public class StatelessPage extends BasePage {
protected String buf = " ";
protected Op op;
protected String input = " ";
protected String current = buf;
public StatelessPage() {
    add(new CalcForm("form"));
}
class CalcForm extends StatelessForm {
    public CalcForm(String id) {
        super(id, new CompoundPropertyModel(StatelessPage.this));
        add(new Label("display", new ComponentPropertyModel("buf")));
        add(new HiddenField("buf"));
        add(new HiddenField("op") {
            @Override
            public IConverter getConverter(Class type) {
                return new IConverter() {
                    public Object convertToObject(String value, Locale locale) {
                        return Strings.isEmpty(value) ? null : Op.valueOf(value);
                    }
                    public String convertToString(Object value, Locale locale) {
                        return value.toString();
                    }
                };
            }
        });
        add(new TextField("input"));


        /*
        add(new OpButton("sevend", Op.digit));
        add(new OpButton("eightd", Op.digit));
        add(new OpButton("nined", Op.digit));*/

        add(new Button("sevend") {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {
                current += input;
                buf += current;
                input += "7";
                op = null;
            }
        });

        add(new Button("eightd") {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {
                current += input;
                buf += current;
                input += "8";
                op = null;
            }
        });

        add(new Button("nined") {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {
                current += input;
                buf += current;
                input += "9";
                op = null;
            }
        });
        add(new OpButton("div", Op.div));

        add(new Button("fourd") {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {
                current = "" + input;
                buf += current;
                input += "4";
                op = null;
            }
        });
        add(new Button("fived") {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {
                current = "" + input;
                buf += current;
                input += "5";
                op = null;
            }
        });
        add(new Button("sixd") {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {
                current += input;
                buf += current;
                input += "6";
                op = null;
            }
        });
        add(new OpButton("mult", Op.mult));


        add(new Button("oned") {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {
                current += input;
                buf += current;
                input += "1";
                op = null;
            }
        });
        add(new Button("twod") {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {
                current += input;
                buf += current;
                input += "2";
                op = null;
            }
        });
        add(new Button("threed") {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {
                current += input;
                buf += current;
                input += "3";
                op = null;
            }
        });
        add(new OpButton("sub", Op.sub));


        add(new Button("zerod") {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {
                current += input;
                buf += current;
                input += "0";
                apply();
            }
        });
        add(new Button("clear") {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {
                buf = "";
                input = "";
                op = null;
            }
        });
        add(new Button("eq") {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {
                apply();
            }
        });
        add(new OpButton("add", Op.add));   
    }
}

void apply() {
    if (op == null)
        buf = input;
    else
        buf = op.eval(new BigDecimal(buf), new BigDecimal(input)).toString();
}

class OpButton extends Button {
    private Op myOp;
    public OpButton(String id, Op myOp) {
        super(id);
        this.myOp = myOp;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSubmit() {
        apply();
        op = myOp;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my calculator:

[image: my calculator]

Comment: Hi! A couple of things looking at your code:
- in OpButton#onSubmit you might invert the instructions: first set the operation then invoke apply.
- Why button "zerod" invokes "apply"?
Last advice: try to refactor number buttons using a common class.